# What sort of code is this?

Tags: programming-languages, pseudocode

Here is a question I encountered:-

Read this section of program code that inputs 10 positive numbers and then outputs the smallest number input. Identify three changes you would need to make to find the largest number input instead of the smallest number.

```
    Small = 1000
    Counter = 0 
    REPEAT
    INPUT Num
    IF Num < Small THEN Small = Num
    Counter = Counter + 1
    UNTIL Counter = 10
    PRINT Small
```

The question refers to a vague 'program code'-which I do not know of. Neither does this seem like pseudocode due to presence of the equals sign as an assigning operator instead of the arrow '←'.Clearly, not a low-level programming language. So what is it?

Note:I am high school student. This code is part of the 0478 Computer Science IGCSE curriculum here:http://www.cambridgeinternational.org/programmes-and-qualifications/cambridge-igcse-computer-science-0478/past-papers/
If anyone of you know about what this code is and why it is used as part of this IGCSE, please include that in your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is still a form of pseudocode, obviously just not of the form you might have seen thus far. It is worth noting that there is not strict standard or rules for writing pseudocode, as long as it describes the solution to a problem in such a way that someone could then implement it in a language of their choice.

The term *pseudocode* simply refers to some notation resembling a programming language, aimed more towards human readability and understanding rather than some language-specific syntax.

Comment: So could I replace the equals sign with the arrow in the solution?

Comment: *an arrow......

Comment: Yes, it seems reasonable to consider both ← and = as assignment notations.